# Warning: Undefined array key appear in multiple file

Tags: php, xampp, undefined

I'm new to programming and now I'm working on a project, this project already have prototype that is made by senior student, but now there's have multiple error in php file, and I can't find a way to contact him, I google a lot and tried many way to fix it but doesn't work, this is really driving me crazy.

here some example:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\warmhouse\aeadmin.php on line 9

 <?php
     $result=All("select * from admin where id='1".$_GET["id"]."'");
     foreach($result as $row)
     {   
     ?>
```

and this one:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\warmhouse\aeditu.php on line 5
" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Warning: Undefined array key "id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\warmhouse\aeditu.php on line 8

<?php 

require_once('sql.php'); ?>
<h1>ChangeMember</h1><br>
<form id="form" method="post" action="api.php?do=editu&id=<?=$_GET["id"]?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php
    $result=All("select *from user where u_id='".$_GET["id"]."'");
      foreach($result as $row)
    {   
    ?>
```

basically it's seems like every file that have $_GET or $_POST something like this will have error, if someone need more information, just ask, I've been trying to solve this by myself several weeks, thank you.

I'm on PC and using xampp and phpmyadmin

Comment: Your question is too broad and unclear.
Please include code from original code files (with line nos.) which are reporting the errors, and also include the error messages.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with phpMyAdmin, which is a web-based application for administrators to manage a MySQL or MariaDB database.

Answer (score 1):

The error explains it perfectly. There's no `id` key in the [`$_GET` parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). If you visit `yoursite.com/aeadmin.php` it will throw an error because you aren't supplying the `id` parameter, but if you visit `yoursite.com/aeadmin.php?id=123` it will run fine.

Add some checks before `$_GET["id"]` is used to check if it exists, and do something else if it does not exist:

```php
if (!isset($_GET["id"])) {
    die ("Missing ID parameter");
}
```

As a tangent, it appears you are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. See [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

//copy this line past on the top of your php code

$id = !isset($_GET['id'])? "" : $_GET['id'];

$qs="select *from user where u_id='".$id."'";

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).